# d3.js Stack Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In reference to this [stack chart on d3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stack.html)

Could somebody explain this chunk of javascript? I may be simply not understanding the fundementals behind javascript, I'm relatively new to it. I understand that the margin between bars is being set, the width of the entire view, the height, but then I get completely lost in the portion below. The entire source is on the mbostock link...thanks in advance.

```
var margin = 20,
width = 960,
height = 500 - .5 - margin,
mx = m,
my = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d, function(d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y;
  });
}),
mz = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d, function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });
}),

x = function(d) { return d.x * width / mx; },
y0 = function(d) { return height - d.y0 * height / my; },
y1 = function(d) { return height - (d.y + d.y0) * height / my; },
y2 = function(d) { return d.y * height / mz; };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am also kind of new to javascript, I'll try to provide my understanding of the code:

`my` calculates the maximum height of the bars when stacked (as `d.y0` is the position of the base, and `d.y` is the height of the bar, so `d.y0 + d.y` represents the height of any particular stacked bar)

Similarly, `mz` calculates the maximum height of the bars when grouped

`d.x` is the index location of the bar, `width / mx` is the pixel space allocated to any group/stack of bars, so the function `x` translates the index to pixel space

Similarly, `y0` and  `y1` are functions to convert the height of stacked bars to pixel space, and `y2` is a function to convert the height of a grouped bar to pixel space